# use old random number in rand function

Tags: php

I am using random number function in php. If browser loads or refresh, rand() generates new random number. But I need, if rand() generates a random number first time, after that, if browser loads then random number should not replace old one. Means I want first random number in session.

My code is:

```
$globalvari = rand();
$_SESSION['globalvari'] = $globalvari;
if ($_SESSION['globalvari'] != '') {
    $globalvari1 = $_SESSION['globalvari'];
    echo $globalvari1;
}
```

But it replace old one.

Comment: use `isset()`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 if(!empty($_SESSION['globalvari']) || (isset($_SESSION['globalvari']) && $_SESSION['globalvari'] === 0)){
      $globalvari1=$_SESSION['globalvari'];
      echo $globalvari1;
 }else{
      $globalvari=rand();
      $_SESSION['globalvari']=$globalvari;
 }
```

You're setting it every reload.  So it has to be in the else condition.  Also, use empty because it doesn't care if the index is set in the array or not.

Last empty will trip up on `int(0)`, so you can bypass that with a simple `OR` and strict comparison.

> Rand() A random integer between min (or 0) and max (or getrandmax() inclusive)

Or you can set a range that does not include `0`

Comment: you should check for 0,

Comment: But its show till second random number also. after click other page.

Answer (score 2):

You should code like this :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['globalvari'])){// Checks that `$_SESSION['globalvari']` exist. If not exist then below code create `$_SESSION['globalvari']` variable
    $globalvari=rand();
    $_SESSION['globalvari']=$globalvari;        
}
$globalvari1=$_SESSION['globalvari'];
echo $globalvari1;
```

Comment: you should provide some detail with your code regarding the error in the OP code and then suggesting what to do

Comment: yeah it ok now, just saying it becomes easy for a learner to understand